# How display popup info in the top right corner?

Tags: javascript, python, leaflet, gis, folium

I was able to display a marker for each part of geography for the USA data (using US data as an example since can't display the work data results) using below:

```
import dload
from shapely.geometry import shape
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import folium

json_string = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/geo-admin1-us/master/data/admin1-us.geojson'

j = dload.json(json_string)

gdf_usa = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(j["features"])
gdf_usa.head()

gdf_usa_new = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gdf_usa, crs="EPSG:4326", geometry='geometry')

usa_map = gdf_usa_new.explore(tiles='CartoDB  positron')
usa_map

gdf_usa_new["long"] = gdf_usa_new.to_crs(epsg='4326').centroid.map(lambda p: p.x)
gdf_usa_new["lat"] = gdf_usa_new.to_crs(epsg='4326').centroid.map(lambda p: p.y)

for i in range(0,len(gdf_usa_new)):
    folium.Marker(
      location=[gdf_usa_new.iloc[i]['lat'], gdf_usa_new.iloc[i]['long']],
      popup=gdf_usa_new.iloc[i]['name'],
      icon=folium.DivIcon(html=f"""<div style="font-family: courier new; color: white">{gdf_usa_new.iloc[i]['name']}</div>""")
   ).add_to(usa_map)

usa_map
```

As can be seen in the map below, the popup appears right where I hover the mouse:

[image]

How can I modify the code so that when I hover over the desired area the information is displayed in the top right corner like below?

[image]

Above screenshot taken from:

https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/

So, I added the code below. However, it does not provide the desired update.

```
my_js = '''
var info = L.control({position: 'topright'});

info.onAdd = function (usa_map) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create a div with a class "info"
    this.update();
    return this._div;
};

// method that we will use to update the control based on feature properties passed
info.update = function (props) {
    this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>US Population Density</h4>' +  (gdf_usa_new ?
        '<b>' + gdf_usa_new + '</b><br />'
        : 'Hover over a state');
};'''
usa_map.get_root().script.add_child(Element(my_js))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Follow the link (https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/). Copy below into the html code (drag the html into the Notepad++). Update "map" to "map_...", just search for "map_" in the text file that opened.

```
var info = L.control();

info.onAdd = function (map) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create a div with a class "info"
    this.update();
    return this._div;
};

// method that we will use to update the control based on feature properties passed
info.update = function (props) {
    this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>US Population Density</h4>' +  (props ?
        '<b>' + props.name + '</b><br />' + props.density + ' people / mi<sup>2</sup>'
        : 'Hover over a state');
};

info.addTo(map);
```

Next, search for "highlight" in the txt file of your html. Add below right under the  function highlighter(feature) or whatever it is called in your file:

```
info.update(layer.feature.properties);
```

Save the notepad++, open your html file, and it should work!